# Определить текущий месяц после какого то количества дней

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Задание звучит следующим образом:
С 1 января 1990 года по некоторый день прошлo m дней, определить название текущего месяца
Есть такой код, он работает, но только для определения месяца с ограничением пройденных дней. Т.е. если ввести что прошло, к примеру, 366 дней, он выведет `else`, а нужно чтобы он вывел снова January.  
*p.s. моя реализация может быть крайне неверная, но это потому что я вообще без понятия как это сделать*

```py
lastSeen = int(input())
if 1 < lastSeen < 31:
    month = "january"
elif 31 < lastSeen < 59:
    month = "February";
elif 59 < lastSeen < 90:
    month =  "March"
elif 90 < lastSeen < 120:
    month = "April"
elif 120 < lastSeen < 151:
    month = "May"
elif 151 < lastSeen < 181:
    month = "June"
elif 181 < lastSeen < 212:
    month = "Jule"
elif 212 < lastSeen < 243:
    month = "August"
elif 243 < lastSeen < 273:
    month = "September"
elif 273 < lastSeen < 304:
    month = "October"
elif 304 < lastSeen < 334:
    month = "November"
elif 334 < lastSeen < 365:
    month = "December"
else:
    month = "Error"


print(month)
```

Comment: А просто к дате *1 января 1990 года* добавить заданное количество дней, и для полученной даты выделить компоненту месяца - не наш метод?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime(year=1990, month=1, day=1)
lastSeen = int(input())
seen = start + timedelta(days=lastSeen)
print(seen.strftime('%B'))
```

А чтобы делать Вашим методом нужно заморачиваться самому с високосными годами и перед этими if вычитать где-то 365, где-то 366 за каждый прошедший год. Но тогда надо задаться до какого года после прошедшего события нужна точность. Иначе и этого может быть недостаточно, если речь о тысячах лет.

Comment: а до нашей эры года были високосными?)

Comment: Здесь задача начинает свой отсчёт с 1990 года нашей эры и идёт в сторону будущего. Что было раньше неважно :) А так надо учитывать погрешность 3 дня на 10 тыс. лет :)

Answer (score 0):

Если не задумываться о погрешности високосных годов то можно просто добавить:

```
    while lastSeen > 366:
    lastSeen = lastSeen - 365
```

Перед проверкой на январь, соответственно

Comment: какой интересный способ выполнить остаток от леления (`%`)))

Comment: Кстати да! Можно же просто поставить `lastSeen = lastSeen % 365` перед проверкой на январь и все. Он будет опять же показывать месяцы. Спасибо!